# Find sum of odd keys in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java

I need to find the sum of odd  keys in a Binary Search Tree

```
public int OddKeys(Node root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int value = 0;
    if (root.key.compareTo(value) % 2 == 0) {
        return value + OddKeys(root.left) + OddKeys(root.right);
    }
    return value + OddKeys(root.left) + OddKeys(root.right);
}
```

I am unable to run this because I am confused on how to set "if (root.key.compareTo(value) % 2 == 0)". What would be the correct way to check if the keys are odd or not.

Comment: Try to explain, in plain English words: 1) what is the purpose of `% 2 == 0` in that line of code? How does it work? 2) Where exactly should the value come from, that you wish to subject to this test? 3) In the context of your binary search tree implementation, what is a "key"? 4) If "the key" is odd, should you add it when computing the value to return? 5) If "the key" is *even*, should you add it when computing the value to return?

Comment: I have reformatted your code. Please try not to mix tabs and spaces in indentation, or to assume that a tab is equivalent to any particular number of spaces. In the long run, it will only result in confusion and ugliness.

Comment: Also, please add your Node class to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that `compareTo(0)` is hoping to do.  If we assume that your keys are simple integers, something like this might be what you're trying to get to:

```
public int OddKeys(Node root) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    int value = (root.key % 2 == 0)? 0 : 1;
    return value + OddKeys(root.left) + OddKeys(root.right);
}
```